# How to play an audio file as speech for an Amazon Sumerian Host?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-polly, amazon-sumerian

I have an mp3 file saved in Amazon S3. I want my Amazon Sumerian host to speak that audio file. So how do I make my Sumerian host speak from that audio file?

Comment: Have you checked out the official tutorial: https://docs.sumerian.amazonaws.com/tutorials/create/beginner/music-and-sound/?

Comment: ya, @ChrisWilliams  I have gone through all. The documentation tells about importing audio, but my question is I want to import this audio as speech for my host and can I do that?

Comment: I want to make sure I understand this question.  You want your host to read an mp3 audio file, convert the audio to text, and then speak the text.  Is this your question?

Comment: ya, the way you interpreted the question is not wrong, the main purpose is I should import an audio mp3 file into my Sumerian project and I want that audio to be spoken as a speech by my host, by any means possible.  I even tried writing a speech file where i tried writing SSML for my host as <speak> <audio src="s3 link to my genrated mp3 audio file" /> </speak>
this also does not work.